# Convex Polytope

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-programming

My Linear Programmation book tells me to consider the closed and limited Convex Polytope defined as

$$S=\left \{ \right.\bar{x}:A\bar{x}=\bar{b} ,\bar{x}\geq 0\left. \right \}$$

But , does this equation **only** define the points that belongs to the hyperplanes that contains the convex polytope ?
Thanks

Comment: It is a strict equality $A\overline x = \overline b$ and no inequality so any solutions must lie on planes or lines and can't lie in the "volume" or what you would call it.

Comment: So , am i right ?

Comment: I don't know.  I am not sure I understand your question.

Comment: A polytope is the set of all points included in a system of hyperplanes or just the points in  the hyperplanes ? Because my book calls polytope the set i wrote in the main post

Comment: $S$ is the set of all $\overline x$ which fulfil both the equality and the inequality. I don't get the question. It seems you are more confused about semantics. I don't know how your book defines those words.

Answer (score 0):

This field is not my meat, but let me try to answer according to my understanding.

This is the intersection of the $(+,+,\dots,+)$-cone of your domain space with a (translated) linear subspace thereof. For instance, if the domain space is just the plane, you’re talking about either a single point in the first quadrant, or the first-quadrant part of a line, or all the first quadrant.

If the domain space is $\Bbb R^3$, you’re looking either at a single point in the first octant, or the first-octant part of a line, or the first-octant part of a plane, or the all the first octant.

I don’t know what the book means by “limited”: if they mean compact, that is certainly not the case; if they mean closed, that is all right.

The set defined here turns out to be convex, but you are making a mistake if you are trying to see this definition as a modification of the book’s definition of a convex set. I would say that there are no hyperplanes specifically mentioned here, though if you search for them, you will find them.